# Compare elements within an array

Tags: java

I am creating a project where the user enters names of multiple sports teams. The user is not allowed to enter the same name of a team twice. I can't figure out how to compare elements of an array. I tried to use a while loop with equals but I don't think it's the right way.

```
for(int i = 0; i<tabEquipe.length;i++){ // tabEquipe is the table content of the teams that the user enters.
        System.out.println("Entrez les noms des equipes: "); // Asks user to enter team names.
        rep2 = a.nextLine();
       tabEquipe[i] = rep2;
       while(tabEquipe[i].equals(tabEquipe[i])){

       }
    }
```

Comment: `tabEquipe[i]` will always equal `tabEquipe[i]` If you have to use an array you could use a second loop to check all positions in the array for duplicates. If you don't have to use an array, another data structure (like a Set) would be easier.

Comment: @Mohamed Did you consider using Set interface instead of Array?

Comment: I thought about it but unfortunately I have to use an Array

Comment: in order to avoid duplicate names just use a HashSet. Its add() method will return false if the element you try to insert is already in the set

Answer (score 1):

That's confusing, so I assume you have already a new user you want to add, and it seems you can compare users with `equals`. If there's a new user `newUser` then it could look like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < tabEquipe.length; i++){ 
   if (tabEquipe[i].equals(newUser))
   {
      found = true;
      break; 
   }
}
```

or, shorter:

```
boolean found = Arrays.asList(tabEquipe).contains(newUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to store the names of teams in such a manner that the check if a new name was already used happens very efficiently. For example:

```
...

Set<String> teamNamesSet = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++) {
 ...

 // Checking if a team name was already used
 while (teamNamesSet.contains(name)) {
  // Show some error message, request input again, etc.
 }

 // Adding a new team name to the set
 teamNamesSet.add(name);

 // Adding a new team name also to the array you need
 teamNames[i] = name;
}
```

The great advantage of this approach is that the check if a name is already in a `HashSet` takes a constant time (`O(1)`). Using a for loop to check has a linear complexity (`O(n)`).

Comment: I'd rather check the response of add() and not calling contains(). Just my personal choice

Comment: It would work as well, and it's a bit more concise.

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Your approach has the disadvantage that you can't forget to call `add` after `contains` and then wonder why the code doesn't work. And don't we all love to debug such stuff?

Comment: I can't understand you. My solution is: if(!teamNamesSet.add(name)} {//show some error}

Comment: @EnricoGiurin I know and can you forget to call `add` there? No, but in Albertos "concise" version you can and then wonder why this code doesn't work. I just wonder if this is a feature since we all love debugging such mistakes.

Comment: I'd change the version of Alberto in this: if (teamNamesSet.contains(name)) {
  // Show some error message, request input again, etc.
 }else{ teamNamesSet.add(name);}

Comment: I imagined that OP wanted to ensure that the user enters a unique name. I changed the `if` to a `while` to enforce this idea, so we would leave the while (or never get into it) only when we have a valid name. But the main takeover from this answer is the usage of `HashSet`. The rest is implementation details. OP would be free to adapt it to what he really needs. Good input from you two, nevertheless :)

Comment: @EnricoGiurin The issue isn't this code itself, it already contains everything you need, the issue is to get used to use contains, because then you can forget to method call to `add` when needed. That is why I suggest to avoid `contains` in such cases like this.

Comment: It makes sense @Tom. It was just not clear to me why before you wrote that my approach has the 'disadvantage' of something. Then we've clarified.

Comment: @EnricoGiurin The disadvantage of _not_ falling into traps by forgetting something important ;P.

Comment: @Tom My bad  I am not native speaker. And apologies for being boring but...should have you said: "The advantage of not falling into..." ? advantage vs disadvantage

Comment: @EnricoGiurin depends on the perspective. For one it could be an advantage to avoid issues for others it can be a disadvantage for not getting the chance to debug such issues.

Comment: Just came across [a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4XkWSAm2XU&feature=youtu.be) that discusses cache friendlyness of data structures on modern cpus, depending on the usage profile there may be pros and cons about arrays or hashsets. but for plain search, hashset is ahead of course.